# Javascript Bookmark to download from youtube to mp3 directly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am editing a javascript code[the code takes me directly to downloading the video to mp3] since the code provided by the website was not working..i tried editing on my own

This is the code below

```
javascript:(function() {if (location.href.indexOf('www.youtube.com') > -1) {var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(location.href).replace(/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch/g,'');var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);window.open("http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/" + uri_dec)}else{alert('sorry youcant');}}) ();
```

Now the problem here is, I have made a bookmark of this code in chrome, The intention of the bookmark is to run the code when I visit the youtube video page and press the bookmark button.

But for some reason the bookmark doesn't seem to work. so I opened up the console and checked the reason..here are the pictures below of the error..

[in console this error comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H7Rn.png)

[on further examining i find that %2F is getting detected as closing '/' so its not detecting the latter part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwvmg.png)

on further examining i find that %2F is getting detected as closing '/' so its not detecting the latter part

Because of that false detection my bookmark is not working.
However the good news is that if I copy paste the code to console directly and execute then it will work succesfully.

But that is too much work.:p for everyday use.

so help me fix the bookmark please.

### UPDATE

Javascript is solved and bookmark is working...
Here below is the complete code..which works for single video and a playlist too..you just need to click on the bookmark when you are on the video page or the playlist page which will direct to download page...

`javascript:(function() {if (location.href.indexOf('www.youtube.com') > -1) {var uri_enc = location.href.replace(/https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch|https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/playlist/g,'');window.open("http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/" + uri_enc);}else{alert('sorry youcant');}}) ();`

I am still learning javascript so it took quiet time to understand the answers but thanks to both the coders who answered especially TigOldBitties who gave the complete code from which I understood what the mistake was...Have a nice day..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slashes so they don't close the regex

```
.replace(/https:\/\/www.youtube.com/, '')
```

LE: The complete answer is that now that you know that you can escape special characters you can drop the needless encoding and just use:

```
javascript:(function() {if (location.href.indexOf('www.youtube.com') > -1) {var uri_enc = location.href.replace(/https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch/g,'');window.open("http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/" + uri_enc);}else{alert('sorry youcant');}}) ();
```

Comment: Like you said I used the escape slashes but now what happens is link loads but it doesn't replace the https:www.youtube.com url....It just loads as it is..for eg: it loads as http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6M0V-74spk instead of http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/?v=o6M0V-74spk

Comment: ,,Thank you so much..now its working,,,i had not removed the encoding part so it wasn't working,..I could have used location.href directly instead of  encodeURIComponent..That is where the mistake was. :)

Comment: I also modified the code slightly using OR ('|') to even download playlists :)..Thought I would share the code `javascript:(function() {if (location.href.indexOf('www.youtube.com') > -1) {var uri_enc = location.href.replace(/https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch|https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/playlist/g,'');window.open("http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/" + uri_enc);}else{alert('sorry youcant');}}) ();`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a bug.

Bookmarks point to URLs.

You happen to have encoded JavaScript into your URL … and a URL into your JavaScript.

You need to escape the `/` twice. Once for the `http:` URL and then again for the `javascript:` URL.

So `/` becomes `%2F` and that becomes `%252F`